# Is there a way to speed up Integrate when the integrand contains a product of polynomials each of which having a large degree?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, polynomials

I have integrals of the form
$$\int_0^\infty\mathrm d x\; e^{-x^2}\;\;(\textrm{Polynomial of degree n})\times(\textrm{Polynomial of degree m}),$$
where $n,m$ can be as large as 300.

When I use `Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]`, the calculation is too slow for large polynomial degrees.

Is there a way to speed up this calculation? (I tried to use NIntegrate, but unfortunately, since the integrand is highly oscillatory at large $n,m$, I'm unable to get reliable results from numerical methods).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps this?:

```
Table[1/2 Gamma[(1 + n)/2], {n, 0, Length@# - 1}] . # &@
 CoefficientList[poly1*poly2, x]
```

Low-order check:

```
poly1 = LaguerreL[4, x];
poly2 = LaguerreL[5, x];

Table[1/2 Gamma[(1 + n)/2], {n, 0, Length@# - 1}] . # &@
 CoefficientList[poly1*poly2, x]

(*  -(7981/240) + (38645 Sqrt[π])/2048  *)

Integrate[Exp[-x^2] poly1*poly2, {x, 0, Infinity}]

(*  -(7981/240) + (38645 Sqrt[π])/2048  *)
```

High-order timing:

```
poly1 = LaguerreL[300, x];
poly2 = LaguerreL[301, x];

Table[1/2 Gamma[(1 + n)/2], {n, 0, Length@# - 1}] . # &@
   CoefficientList[poly1*poly2, x]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.957942, Null}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Can you add some description of what the code actually does? I'm not very experienced in Mathematica, so I don't actually understand your code :D

Comment: @temporal99x $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} x^n \, dx = {1\over2} \Gamma\left[{n+1 \over 2}\right]$, so $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \sum_n a_n x^n \, dx = \sum_n a_n\,{1\over2} \Gamma\left[{n+1 \over 2}\right]$.  `CoefficientList` gives us the $a_n$ and the `.` makes the `Dot` product with the list/table of gamma function values. -- It could be broken down into three steps: `an = CoefficientList[poly1*poly2, x];
gammafactors = Table[1/2 Gamma[(1 + n)/2], {n, 0, Length@an - 1}];
an . gammafactors`

Comment: @temporal99x A couple of other ways to speed up `Integrate`, but they're not as fast as the method above. Both assume the integral is convergent: **(1)** `Integrate[Exp[-x^2] poly1*poly2, {x, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]` **(2)** `Integrate[Exp[-x^2] poly1*poly2, x] /. {{x -> 0}, {Exp[-x^2] -> 0, Erf[x] -> 1}} // Differences // First`

Comment: I now fully understand your solution. It is just beautiful, and fast! You may not know how helpful this is to me.

Comment: @temporal99x I'm glad to be of help. Here is a slightly faster way to calculate the coefficients of the product of two polynomials: `an = ListConvolve[CoefficientList[poly1, x],  CoefficientList[poly2, x], {1, -1}, 0];`